# Spider-Gwen timing

Tags: plot-explanation, spider-man-into-the-spider-verse

*This question contains spoilers about Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse.*

How come Spider-Gwen appeared on class along Miles if the collider accident happened after?

Is the only spider-being that seems to be on Miles univers before than the others.

How was this explained in the movie (as I dont recall this being explained)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the movie Gwen mentions that she was warped back a week into the past.

Screenplay<sup>*</sup>:

> Gwen EXPLODES IN AN ENERGY BURST OUT OF THE COLLIDER.
>   GWEN (V.O.)
>
> I was blown into last week.
>   Literally. I landed in New York.
>   But not my New York.

*<sub>Full script link: https://t.co/CO2EQCKdD3</sub>

Comment: Mhh although there is interdimensional travel, its weird that she came back a week (and the only one)... Thanks mate!

Comment: Does the movie explain how the spider got back in time, or is it just presumably the same way?

Comment: @lois6b She might not have been the only one. We don't know when any of the others arrived except for Peter. They may have been waiting at Aunt May's for others for any amount of time.