# How did Gwen come to this universe even before the portal was open?

Tags: plot-explanation, spider-man-into-the-spider-verse

So as we all know Gwen came into the picture even before the portal was open in *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse*, while other Spidermen came into the current universe after the portal was open and the main Spiderman died.

How did that happen? Did Wilson Fisk open the portal before that fight as well?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The other question is about *why*, this is about *when*.

Comment: This is not the duplicate of the marked question

Comment: I agree with the other comments. Gwen appears in the movie _prior_ to the portal being opened. There is no obvious explanation (and it is also not explained in the "duplicate" question) to why she appears before the portal opens up. In fact the other question gives even more evidence (spidermans head entering the portal) for gwen not to be transported before that very event.

Comment: Laslavinco, this question might be what you are looking for though: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96074/spider-gwen-timing

Comment: @kevin yep that answers my question. Thanks a ton. 